# Spaces between recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am getting spaces between my recyclerview and the imageslider.

This is my fragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
    custom:auto_cycle="true"
    custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
    custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>

<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
    custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
    custom:shape="oval"
    custom:selected_padding_left="5dp"
    custom:selected_padding_right="5dp"
    custom:unselected_padding_left="5dp"
    custom:unselected_padding_right="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    custom:selected_width="6dp"
    custom:selected_height="6dp"
    custom:unselected_width="6dp"
    custom:unselected_height="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />
<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator2"
    style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval_Orange"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:layout_below="@+id/custom_indicator"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_indicator"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[![layout][1]][1]

1-What did i do wrong so my recycler view items are far separated?

2-Also when i swipe the items from bottom they hide under the imageslider..what to do?

Please i need help

UPDATED: 
 Recycler layout for displaying the items in the recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Grey_50"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_news"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_news_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_news"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image_news"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/recent"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_recent"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_timedate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/recent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recent"
                    android:text="20:49"
                    android:textColor="@color/Grey_600"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-What did i do wrong so my recycler view items are far separated?**

Remove `custom_indicator2` from XML and also remove attribute `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"` from `custom_indicator`.

**2-Also when i swipe the items from bottom they hide under the imageslider..what to do?**

Remove attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

**Update your XML as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
        custom:auto_cycle="true"
        custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
        custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
        custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
        custom:shape="oval"
        custom:selected_padding_left="5dp"
        custom:selected_padding_right="5dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_left="5dp"
        custom:unselected_padding_right="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        custom:selected_width="6dp"
        custom:selected_height="6dp"
        custom:unselected_width="6dp"
        custom:unselected_height="6dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:** I think the problem is in your `recycler` item view. Remove `ScrollView` from item layout.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/Grey_50"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_news_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_news"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_news"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/recent"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_recent"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_timedate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/recent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recent"
                android:text="20:49"
                android:textColor="@color/Grey_600"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Sorry it didn t work..same result 
I will edit my question and post my layout for dispalying the items

Comment: Ohh u got tired with me it works ! Thank you u saved me it was the scrollview issue.

But please if u got a solution if i would swipe the reyclerview from bottom to top it stills hide the items under the imageslider

Comment: I mean "Scrolling" not swiping

Comment: Happy to help you. If you want to scroll both image slider and recyclerview when swipe up, then you can use android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout as root layout instead of LinearLayout. For this case you should use  attribute app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to  SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: try again with setting app:layout_behavior to slider layout. If its not work, use NestedScrollview as root layout and place your previous LinearLayout inside NestedScrollview.

Comment: <3 the swipe worked perfectly but only something left is "Scrolling" the recyclerview from bottom to top hides some of the items under the imageslider

Comment: No need to nestedScrollView it worked with CoordinatorLayout